# Avoiding watchers with AngularJS on Object.defineProperty

Tags: angularjs, breeze, single-page-application

I have extended my entities, which are provided by breezejs, with properties that are the result of a recursive call to the property.  The property is display only and I never want to store the value.

In particular I added a "start" and an "end" property which depends on the "end" date of the entity before it and the timespan of the current entity.  These values are deterministic and there is no sense in storing them.  This works brilliantly until I have a few thousand entities.  At this point performance tanks due to the two way binding as a result of all of the properties that were touched during the calculation.

I have a caching scheme in place and simply want angularjs to do nothing during the calculation of the "start" and "end" properties.

How can I prevent any watchers/two way binding from occurring while I am calculating these properties?

In a broader sense, how can you work with large amounts of data within angularjs without drowning in watchers?

**Edit:**

Something like this appears to be the solution:
https://coderwall.com/p/d_aisq/speeding-up-angularjs-s-digest-loop

Where the watchers in the scope are suspended during an operation and then resumed after I am done.

```
var watches = scope.$$watchers;
scope.$$watchers = [];

// do fast computation that touches a lot of data

scope.$$watchers = watchers;
```

**Edit 2:**

This is before binding to the view, this is in assembly data for binding.  I don't think one time bindings can be done in the controller?

Comment: You can use one-time binding. Also displaying a few thousand entities at once seems like a bad idea anyway. Your last question is far too broad. It's like asking "How can I write fast code".

Comment: This question feels like it lacks the detail necessary to provide a solid, focused answer.  it's not really clear the way the question is presented where the calculation is being performed, much less why you would perform "thousands of calculations" on a single page.

Comment: @Claies sorry to be vague, honestly its a bit intentional.

Comment: @zeroflagL yes, that was poorly worded.    The thousands of items are displayed graphically, in a way that is accessible.  I'll see if I can artifact a small jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Like @zeroflagL's suggestion, one time binding is an option that's available

> An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value

[Expressions @ angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Also, if you want to start a calculation that won't trigger a digest cycle, don't change any members on the $scope. Just use "var" and in the end of the process do $scope.data = newValue;

Comment: So the problem is that the data I am reading from is in scope and I essentially want to read it.  Simply getting a copy of the object that is in scope out of scope would be nice.